# How to get a part of HTML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing, c#-4.0

please consider this scenario:

we have two web page. a simple page that contains some controls and another page that `Execute` first page and get output `HTML`. for example:

```
StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("Blinker.aspx", textWriter);
Label1.Text= Server.HtmlEncode(textWriter.ToString());
```

and it returns this(for example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
    <title> </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form method="post" action="Blinker.aspx" id="form1"> 
    <div class="aspNetHidden"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZKwUTjEtU7qJweOD/x+Op0ROdM+jDqyILuizFGhjOJQj" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="blink"> Some Test</div> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

the problem is if I want just:

```
<div class="blink"> Some Test</div>
```

how I can get it from output html in C#?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: why not extract the '<div class="blink"> Some Test</div>' to a user control, then render just that user control?

Comment: becuase some other people designed that pages and now they can't change them by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the options

1. Apply regular expression to extract this text from response HTML
2. Make XML document, Iterate through all the dive tags.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx Refer this URL

Answer (score 4):

Give the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.ne) a try.

It's a lovely HTML parser that is commonly recommended for this. It will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM, like the XML classes. So, is very useful for the code you find in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

```
HtmlElementCollection tData = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

            foreach (HtmlElement td in tData)
            {
                string name = "";
                if (td.GetAttribute("classname") == "blink")
                {
                    name = td.InnerText;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

we have had the same scenario in one of our project. I would suggest both `Regex` and `HTMLAgilityPack`

- Using the Agilitypack you can filter out the particular content from the web page with C# code and you also have `LINQ` there
- Then if you need to fetch any particluar text within the Div or any individual value there you can make you of Regex.

Hope this helps