# Getting value from string using specific conditions

Tags: c#, string

I have an html data in my string in which i need to get only paragraph values.Below is a sample html.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
       <script>
          <div>
               Some contents
           </div>
          <div>
            <p> This is what i want </p>
            <p> Select all data from p </p>
            <p> Upto this is required </p>
          </div>
         <div>
          Other html elements
         </div>
```

So how to get the data from the paragraphs using string manipulation.

Desired Output

```
<Div>
  <p> This is what i want    </p>
  <p> Select all data from p </p>
  <p> Upto this is required  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer to this question..(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363526/how-to-get-a-part-of-html-in-c-sharp/12363632#12363632)

Comment: Do you just want to get all div elements which have p elements inside them, or just p elements in the whole document?

Comment: I tried with xpath. But my html is not well formatted. So couldnt succeeded.

Comment: @tranceporter: p elements in specific div tag.

Comment: if you want a specific div tag, then you will need some mechanism to uniquely identify it. You will have to assign an id to it. Otherwise you will have to select all divs which have p elements. Check my updated answer

Comment: Adding desired Output will increase the clarity of question. I have worked the similar structure and to be frank unless and until your html formatted, you will have to find & create ur own function to tackle all the cases.

Comment: @Sangram: My issue is i am getting output html data from some websites. So its really cumbersome to format those large htmls. In that output html, I just want contents only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div an ID, e.g.

```
<div id="test">
<p> This is what i want </p>
<p> Select all data from p </p>
<p> Upto this is required </p>
</div>
```

then use `//div[@id='test']/p`.

The solution broken down:

```
//div                    - All div elements
[@id='test']   - With an ID attribute whose value is test
/p
```

Comment: But what if I have several div elements. How to sort the single div which contains the <p> tag.

Comment: Use an ID instead, so it will be for a unique div. I'll edit my answer to show this.

Comment: Let me try this. Will let you know.

Comment: Ok yeah let me know how it goes. You said to me that you just want specific p tags but in the comment on your answer you said all p tags? Use either class or div depending on if you want to get multiple div's of p tags or just one unique div's p tags.

Comment: Just one unique div's p tags. I want all p tags present in one unique div. In the eg above, i want output as : this is what i want select all data from p upto this is required

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Html agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for something like this. Then you can use LINQ to get what you want.

Comment: I am using c# 2.0. So linq is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is the obvious answer (if the HTML is decent, has a root etc), failing that some third party widget like [chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Html Agility Pack as mentioned in the other posts, you can get all paragraph elements in the html by using:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("your html string");
var pNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='id of the div']/p")
```

Since you are using .net Framework 2.0, you would want an older version of Agility Pack, which can be found here: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/releases/view/272)

If you want just the text inside the paragraph, you can use

```
var pNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='id of the div']/p/text()")
```